# Why does 'dig <domain.com> ANY' time out?

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

I've tried to query for 'any' records using dig, and I almost always get a timeout error.

but when i google for why this is the case, there doesn't seem to be any answer at all.

```
psmith@pop-os:~$ dig +short google.com
142.251.35.174
psmith@pop-os:~$ dig +short google.com any
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `ANY`.

It does not do what you (everyone) think it does. It does not fetch "ALL" records from the zone, it never did that. So it is in fact useless. No matter what your problem was, using `ANY` is **NOT** the answer.

It is now even officially permitted for servers to refuse answering that kind of queries or returning useless content, see RFC 8482.

Comment: Then what to use instead to see all entries?